# Do you assign a person to a task or a task to a person

Tags: word-choice

In a web application the system should generate summary reports. Which is natural to say?

*When an assignment is done:*

> Ted assigned Mary to task 33.

or

> Ted assigned task 33 to Mary.

If later the assigned-to field is changed to `<nobody>` what should we add to the report?

> Ted resigned Mary from task 33.

or ... what?

Comment: Yes.  Either or both.  "Assignment" is basically just drawing a (conceptual) line between two things, indicating that they are somehow associated.  Normally you'd assign Mary to the task if the task was all she would be doing for a period of time, but assign the task to Mary if she may be doing several tasks at once.

Comment: ... as a look at definitions 1 and 3 for _assign_ at AHDEL would tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the second question: "Ted removed Mary from task 33."(especially if there are still others assigned to it.) You could also say "Ted unassigned Mary from task 33."
You would not use "resigned" because resign" is something one does on one's own behalf, not for others.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add that I believe the order of assignment does imply a slightly different connotation: *assigning X to Y* implies that you are currently editing Y and have assigned X to it, and not the reverse.  This is merely a connotation and does not alter the underlying meaning of the change that has just been effected.

As an example, if you are writing task-management software and are looking for a confirmation message, it would be seen as somewhat unusual to be told "Task 33 has been assigned to Mary" if you are editing Task 33 at the moment.  While unambiguous and technically correct, the phrasing would run counter to typical word flow in these types of applications.  You would instead expect to be told "Mary has been assigned to Task 33" if you are editing Task 33, or perhaps even "Mary has been assigned to this task" if the user is still clearly editing the task in question.